# How can I install Ubuntu onto a 16GB USB and run on Pi?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 model B V1.1 and I want to download Ubuntu onto the Pi with it's existing 8GB SD card or with an 16GB USB. Can someone please help me?

Comment: If you are going to answer this question can you try find a way to do it with the USB not sd card because my PC does not have a SD card port

Comment: Ubuntu or Ubuntu Mate. For Ubuntu Mate look here:https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/ On site it's written that you need 6 GB SD, but not long ago there was a problem and you needed 16 GB. I do not know if this is corrected. Transfering the image depends if you have Windows or Linux home computer.

Comment: Then you're going to need to buy an adapter for your SD card. There is no way to setup the RPi without doing at least the bare minimum with the SD card.

Comment: I use windows 10 pro and I also have a MacBook with a sd card slot.I don't mind about ubuntu and ubuntu mate I just want the one that performs best.

Comment: @Kyle if you want the best performing, use Raspbian. It's specifically created for the pi and should not have issues.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Mate:

Download Ubuntu Mate for RPi 2 from [here](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/). As you said that only your MacBook has SD card slot you will have to do it there (or buy SD card adapter to use it on Win 10 computer). The downloaded file is compressed (zip) so it has to be un-ziped first (I do not own Apple, but I was told that by double-clicking on the zip file it should automatically unzip it into the same folder). Than insert your SD card (make sure that write-protection pin is not on). You need to know what "name" has been given to SD by your computer (`diskN`, where `N` is a number). Write to command line:

```
diskutil list
```

Find your SD card. Be sure that this is SD. If you get this wrong you could write the image to your system disk and make your MacBook a brick).

Unmount the SD with:

`diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN` ... change `N` to the number you found from above command.

And now transfer the unzipped Ubuntu Mate image to SD card:

```
dd if=/path/to/ubuntu-mate-mage-for-raspberry-pi.img of=/dev/diskN bs=1m
```

Again, change `N` to the number you found in `diskutil list`

Note that it can take a while.

Look at [this](https://gist.github.com/jordelver/3139365), [this](http://www.thelinuxdaily.com/2010/01/writing-images-to-disk-on-mac-osx-with-dd/) or [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md) link for help.